# c# Switch case does not continue after try catch - Need a loop to enter a valid data type

Tags: c#, switch-statement, try-catch, case

When i introduce the "try" "catch" statements and read the user input for the "choice" variable, the code executes as it should it does not however continue on to the "switch" "case" statement as the "choice" variable is then said to be an unassigned local variable. Please help.

I was expecting the rest of the "switch case" code to execute.

```cs
int choice;

do
{
    Console.Clear();
    Console.WriteLine("1. Load Data");
    Console.WriteLine("2. Add Customer");
    Console.WriteLine("3. Sort Customers");
    Console.WriteLine("4. Display Customers");
    Console.WriteLine("5. Edit Customer");
    Console.WriteLine("6. Exit\n");
    Console.WriteLine("Chose an option 1-6: ");

    bool valid = true;
    do
    {
        try
        {
            choice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            valid = false;
            Console.WriteLine("please enter a number from 1 - 6");
        }
    } while (valid == false);
    switch (choice)
    {
        case 1:
            break;
        case 2:
            break;
        case 3:
            break;
        case 4:
            break;
        case 5:
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    Console.Clear();
} while (choice != 6);
```

Comment: Can you post the code you are having trouble with.

Comment: Sorry, just getting used to this website. I have pasted the code, thanks guys :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the `catch` block is executed, then `choice` is not assigned a value in the `try` block.

Assign a value to choice in the `catch` block

```cs
int choice; // Choice is declared here but is not assigned a value.

...

try
{
    // When the conversion fails, no assignment to `choice` is made.
    choice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    valid = true; // This was also missing.
}
catch (Exception)
{
    valid = false;
    choice = 0; // <========================================
    Console.WriteLine("please enter a number from 1 - 6");
}

...

// Now, here `choice` is known to have a value assigned in any case.
```

Note that the compiler does not consider the value of `valid` nor does the compiler analyze how it affects the control flow when is says that `choice` may be unassigned. The error message is based solely on a static analysis of the control flow for assignments made to `choice` itself.

But it would be easier to use `TryParse` instead of catching an exception.

```cs
int choice;
do {
    // Console output ...
    while (!Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out choice)) {
        Console.Write("please enter a number from 1 - 6: ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
    switch (choice) {
        ...
        default:
            break;
    }
    Console.Clear();
} while (choice != 6);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your contribution sir. I have assigned a value to the choice in the catch block and the code executes as it should however as I then proceed to enter the correct data type in the form of int from  1 to 6 the loop does not progress onto the switch-statement; it is stuck in the catch loop.

Comment: Because once you have set `valid = false` you never set it back to `true` in the loop.

Comment: Amazing! works like a charm. TryParse is a much easier way of going about this problem. Thank you very much again.

Answer (score 0):

Sir I think i have just solved it. I have added a Break; statement to the try block. in this case the code loops back to the beginning and allows the user to enter the correct data type again and the switch statement continues.

```
            bool valid = true;
            do
            {
                try
                {
                    choice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    break;
                    
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    valid = false;
                    choice = 0;
                    Console.WriteLine("please enter a number from 1 - 6");
    

                }
                
            } while (valid == false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just assign a value when you decleare `choice`

```
int choice = 0;
```

You have also to set the `valid` variable at `true` at the start of the loop.

```
            bool valid;
            do
            {
                valid = true;
                try
                {
                    choice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    valid = false;
                    Console.WriteLine("please enter a number from 1 - 6");
                }
            } while (valid == false);
```